# Factor vs. Covariate in SPSS MIXED

Tags: spss, categorical-data, mixed-model, predictor

I am using the MIXED command in SPSS to run a multilevel model and was wondering what the difference is when using a dummy coded factor either as factor (via the BY command) or as a covariate (via the WITH) command.
A similar question was already posted here: [BY and WITH command in mixed model SPSS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23314/by-and-with-command-in-mixed-model-spss)
In this thread the issue, however, was the NOINT option.

In my case I am using the intercept and running a simple actor-partner model with 2 metric covariates and one dummy variable (0/1) that distinguishes between two groups. What I am doing is to interact the dummy with both metric variables.

Now, if I use the dummy as a factor (via BY) I get different results for the two main effects, as compared to when I use the dummy as a covariate (via WITH). Aso the estimate and t-value for the Intercept differ.

Can anybody shed light onto this issue and explain why this is the case? I am puzzled.

Comment: Did you make sure that, when SPSS generates its own dummy codes with BY, the reference category is the same category as the one with a value of 0 on your own dummy codes? (i.e., did you make sure that the reference category is the same when using BY vs. WITH)

Comment: As a matter of fact I didn't. You're absolutely right that is the source of the difference in outputs. So SPSS treats refernce categories of factors differently than other statistical software, such as R. Thank you very much for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this issue is the refernce category created by SPSS when using the "BY" statement. It was the inverse of the initial coding of the dummy variable. So note to self and to everybody else: Check the meaning of the refernce categries of your factors, especially when a statistial software interferes.

Comment: This is why I never let software create my dummies automatically. Sure, it's easier, but if I screwed up by forgetting what was what, I want to know about it. So I avoid i. in Stata, by in SPSS, class in SAS and as.factor() in R.